# angular routerLink does not work in component with module

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use RouterLink but nothing happens.

I have two components, the category and the savecategory. the savecategory is defined in the app.module in the declarations part and the category has its own module. so I'm importing your module into imports

**App.module**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SavecategoriaComponent // <~ savecategory
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    LoginModule,
    CategoriaModule,           // <~~CategoryModule
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**app-routing**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },  
  { path: 'categoria', component: CategoriaComponent },
  { path: 'categoria/:id', component: CategoriaComponent },
  { path: 'savecategoria', component: SavecategoriaComponent },
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login' }
];
```

**Category.module**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,   
    HttpClientModule 
  ],
  declarations: [
    CategoriaComponent
  ]
})
```

I'm using the following router to go to login screen

```
<a routerLink="/">Home</a>
```

works perfectly in the savecategory but not in the category.

Is there any missing import in the category?

Comment: Have you tried `[routerLink]="['/']"` ?

Comment: an not bind to 'routerLink' since it is not a known property of 'a'.

Comment: In your `AppRoutingModule` did you `import {  RouterModule } from '@angular/router';`?

Comment: yes, even because I can use routing in my savecategory

Comment: You need to import const routes to app.module and include them in RouterModule.forRoot()

Comment: How can I do this? send me a response so I can accept

Comment: where do you get ''routerLink' since it is not a known property of 'a'. '?

Comment: when I put it in tag "a"

Answer (score 2):

The Categories Module requires you to import the RouterModule for the 'routerLink' directive to work in your template.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The routes array of routes describes how to navigate. Pass it to the RouterModule.forRoot method in the module imports to configure the router.

I included the routes const in the app.module.ts

app.module.ts (excerpt):

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
....

const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },  
  { path: 'categoria', component: CategoriaComponent },
  { path: 'categoria/:id', component: CategoriaComponent },
  { path: 'savecategoria', component: SavecategoriaComponent },
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login' }
];

@NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        SavecategoriaComponent // <~ savecategory
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes), //here for instance add it
        HttpModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        LoginModule,
        CategoriaModule,           // <~~CategoryModule
        NgbModule.forRoot()
      ],
        providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

[Docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#routeroutlet)

Comment: when I try to import routes the following message appears in the exported member 'routes'.

Comment: Which message appears? Could you try adding it in your app.module.ts as I did to check if it works? And then you can import it.

Comment: has no exported member 'routes'.

Comment: Yes because you need to add export keyword in your app-routing.ts to be able to export the const and then import it in the app.module.ts. that is why I placed it in the app.module.ts to make it simpler.

Comment: I managed to do what you showed, but I still did not get results. did not work

Comment: ok, then probably something else is missing or is misconfigured

Comment: Strange my project is basically this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176360/discussion-between-kboul-and-emiry-mirella).

Answer (score -1):

Should work if all is done right, check the routing for the category module, most likely there's no route to handle that link.